# How to take a screen capture of an lwuit app, but not in simulator

Tags: java, graphics, java-me, lwuit

I have an LWUIT app that has a few components that don't display correctly in the simulator.  I need to take some screen captures for docs and was hoping I could do it in code (running on the handset) by either invoking an Image method or a Form method.

No luck so far.

Answer (score 1):

1. Simple alternative try another emulator... or change your code slightly so it looks better in the emulators.
2. Use something like http://deviceanywhere.com or any other real world device emulation programs and take a screen shot using standard means. ;)
3. There are ways... they all seem to involve hacks though.

   You can override the paint method of your particular form.. Create an image get graphics object from said image pass that into paint method... save image to phones SD card or post it to a server.

   You might need to call the paint method another time using the original graphics object if you intend to see what is drawn on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Dont know if this is available to you in LWUIT, but check out: [link text](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/13/screen-image/)